# rvest missing nodes --> NA

Tags: r, parsing, rvest

I'm trying to search for nodes in an html document using rvest in R. In the code below, I would like to know how return a NULL or NA when "s_BadgeTop*" is missing. It is only for academic purpose.

```
<div style="margin-bottom:0.5em;"><div><div style="float:left;">Por&nbsp;</div><div style="float:left;"><a href="/gp/pdp/profile/XXX" ><span style = "font-weight: bold;">JOHN</span></a> (UK)  - <a href="/gp/cdp/member-reviews/XXX">Ver todas las opiniones</a><br /><span class="cmtySprite s_BadgeTop1000 " ><span>(TOP 1000 COMENTARISTAS)</span></span></div></div></div>

<div style="margin-bottom:0.5em;"><div><div style="float:left;">Por&nbsp;</div><div style="float:left;"><a href="/gp/pdp/profile/YYY" ><span style = "font-weight: bold;">MARY</span></a> (USA)  - <a href="/gp/cdp/member-reviews/YYY">Ver todas las opiniones</a><br /></div></div></div>

<div style="margin-bottom:0.5em;"><div><div style="float:left;">Por&nbsp;</div><div style="float:left;"><a href="/gp/pdp/profile/ZZZ" ><span style = "font-weight: bold;">CANDICE</span></a> (UK)  - <a href="/gp/cdp/member-reviews/ZZZ">Ver todas las opiniones</a><br /><span class="cmtySprite s_BadgeTop500 " ><span>(TOP 500 COMENTARISTAS)</span></span></div></div></div>
```

I need a data.frame with this structure:

1. JOHN          (TOP 1000 COMENTARISTAS)
2. MARY          NA
3. CANDICE       (TOP 500 COMENTARISTAS)

I have tried this code:

```
name <- pg %>%
html_nodes(xpath='//a[contains(@href,"/gp/pdp/profile/")]') %>%
html_text

status <- pg %>%
html_nodes(xpath='//span[contains(@class,"cmtySprite s_BadgeTop")]')  %>% 
html_text
status[is.na(status)] <- "NA"
```

but status[is.na(status)] <- "NA" does not work.

I get this output:

1. JOHN          (TOP 1000 COMENTARISTAS)
2. MARY          (TOP 500 COMENTARISTAS)
3. CANDICE       (TOP 1000 COMENTARISTAS)

Thanks!

Comment: It is hardly to reproduce your problem. What happens with status where there were't `cmtySprite s_BadgeTop` class? Have you tried with `tryCatch` function?

Comment: If no "cmtySprite s_BadgeTop", the value of CANDICE is assigned to MARY. On other occasions I 've solved using " cssApplyInNodeSet " but do not know how to combine rvest and css.

Comment: Where is any `CANDICE` or  `MARY` in your question :|? I'm afraid no one will be able to help you unless you provide detailed information and reproducible example ;/

Comment: In HMTL code I have included the rewiewers' name. On the one hand, I show the names (i.e., JOHN, MARY, CANDICE), and the other hand, the status (TOP 1000 COMENTARISTAS or TOP 500 COMENTARISTAS). I have clarified my question above.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over each of the three entries, extract name and - potentially the badge - from it, and ultimately merge all your results.

Example:

```
# For rbindlist
library(data.table)

# Function to parse a particular 'div' and extract name and (potentially) badge
parse_node <- function(node) {
  name <- node %>% 
    html_node('a[href^="/gp/pdp/profile"]') %>%
    html_text
  badge <- node %>%
    html_nodes('span[class*="s_BadgeTop"] span') %>%
    html_text
  list(name=name[1],badge=badge[1])
}

# extract nodes, parse and merge
pg %>%  
  html_nodes('div[style^="margin-bottom"] div div[style^=float]:nth-child(2)') %>%
  lapply(parse_node) %>%
  rbindlist
```